# box-shadow behaviour on <td> elements

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

**Update:**

After I filed a bug report: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=763337,

it seems we could have it fixed in Chrome version 62.

---

Try to hover the td elements of this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1q98o385/3/) in the newest versions of Chrome and Firefox.

Firefox works like a charm (in my opinion, a box-shadow should not add anything to the width / height calculations), but Chrome sadly adds scrollbars (try hovering the bottom right cell).

How can I prevent that from happening, but still keep the responsiveness?

This behaviour only seems to occur when using the absolutely newest Chrome version. Which for me is:

> Version 61.0.3163.79 (Official Build) (64-Bit)

Just tested the code snippet on my notebook which still had a slightly older version installed. Result: no scrollbars while hovering.
After the automatic update and a restart, the scrollbars appeared.

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid green;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

td:hover {
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 15px -2px rgb(50, 50, 50);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>This is some content</td>
      <td>This is some content</td>
      <td>This is some content</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>This is some content</td>
      <td>This is some content</td>
      <td>This is some content</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't have the mentioned behavior on chrome...

Comment: I do (Chrome 61 on Windows)

Comment: this has to be a bug... just noticed 61 is downloading currently so can't test. But try adding overflow:hidden ?

Comment: I'm not seeing this behaviour. I'm on a Mac Chrome Version 61.0.3163.79.

Comment: Just a point of contention... "in my opinion, a box-shadow should not add anything to the width / height calculations" what a property does or does not do is not dependent upon your opinion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like bug of Chrome on [Windows only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46112995/box-shadow-behaviour-on-td-elements#comment79189474_46112995). I tested also in [Google Canary](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/canary.html) (Chrome 63) and the problem persists so it is possible that it may not being fixed so soon.

The problem is caused by `overflow: auto`, in your case it can be easly solved by removing it or setting as visible (default).

**However** when hovering the cells at the right (top and bottom) the scroll bar appear for the body. A solution can be setting `overflow: hidden` for the body so the espected results is as desired.

I would like to note that this is not a great solution but I suggest to use it temporarly until this bug has been fixed.

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

div {
  border: 1px solid green;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: visible;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

td:hover {
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 15px -2px rgb(50, 50, 50);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>This is some content</td>
      <td>This is some content</td>
      <td>This is some content</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>This is some content</td>
      <td>This is some content</td>
      <td>This is some content</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you considered reporting this as a regression issue? I've peeked for similar reports and found http://crbug.com/673646 - it is marked as "wontfix", but since we know for sure something similar was working properly until current update, perhaps it would be worth reviving. (BTW I can also confirm this: have tried with Chrome 60 on W10 - OK, updated and not OK.)

Comment: @myf I did wrote a bug report this morning ;) And as it seems the bug will be fixed in Chrome version 62.

Answer (score -1):

I've used flex-box, as it is easy and very much responsive.

Here is the code:

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid green;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
}

tr {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
}

td {
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

td:hover {
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 15px -2px rgb(50, 50, 50);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>This is some content</td>
      <td>This is some content</td>
      <td>This is some content</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>This is some content</td>
      <td>This is some content</td>
      <td>This is some content</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Who said anything about responsiveness, and how does this solve the issue? Most of all, why are you converting a *table* to flexbox?

Answer (score -2):

i think with chrome. you can try to
-webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 15px -2px rgb(50, 50, 50);

Comment: This does not change the bahaviour.